# multiple button activities on same page - android eclipse

Tags: android, button, android-activity, forceclose

I've tried searching for many methods of utilizing multiple buttons on the same page. I can get the first button to work but the second and third buttons force-close. Does anyone have any idea why this may be? I think that it might be the syntax - but I could be wrong since I'm new to this. Thanks in advance.

Main Java:

```
package com.pangolin.rollin.ts;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class TeamSupport extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_team_support);
          Button wireless=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_wireless);
          Button tools=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_tools);
          Button about=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_about);
          wireless.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myintent1 = new Intent(TeamSupport.this,Wireless.class);
                startActivity(myintent1);

            }
        });
          tools.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent myintent2 = new Intent(TeamSupport.this,Tools.class);
                    startActivity(myintent2);

                }
            });
          about.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

              public void onClick(View v) {
                  Intent myintent3 = new Intent(TeamSupport.this,About.class);
                  startActivity(myintent3);
              }
          });
    }
}
```

Main XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/make_selection"
        android:textColor="#3F9BBF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/beta_notice"
        android:textColor="#3F9BBF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/credits"
        android:textColor="#3F9BBF" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_wireless"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/button_wireless"
        android:textColor="#3F9BBF" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_tools"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button_wireless"
        android:text="@string/button_tools"
        android:textColor="#3F9BBF" />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/button_about"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button_tools"
        android:text="@string/button_about"
        android:textColor="#3F9BBF" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Android Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pangolin.rollin.ts"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="Beta 0.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".TeamSupport"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_team_support" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Wireless"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_wireless"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".About"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_about"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Tools"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tools"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: can you post the error log?? do your activities have layout attached to them???

Comment: Please remove action tag from your other activities from  mainfest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just implement  OnClickListener.

```
now tools.setOnClickListener(this);

   @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.R.id.button_wireless:
    Intent myintent1 = new Intent(TeamSupport.this,Wireless.class);
            startActivity(myintent1);
    break;
```

}

please try this is work better and occupy memory less.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following code

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
</intent-filter>
```

from manifest.xml

Wireless ,About and Tool Activity Tags